# Simulating KeyEvent to trigger AccessibilityService callbacks

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I need help with Android accessibility. I'm trying to simulate the `KeyEvent`s that trigger the `onKeyEvent` callback using the `adb shell input` command. However, it turns out that only actual key presses or gestures are triggering the Accessibility API callbacks.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this callback trigger on a non-rooted device?